# How to open Details and Options in Help Browser by default?

Tags: front-end, configuration

One of minor inconveniences for me is when I invoke the Help browser for a context symbol (or via search, does not matter), the *Details and Options* section cell is closed, and I must click to open it. For me, this is the main part of the reference, so I'd prefer it rather not be collapsed by default.

I believe I could have edited its stylesheet `Reference.nb` in the installation directory, but that seems to me kind of heavy-handed, and I'll lose the change on upgrade, or, even worse, may interfere with it.

Is there a more kosher way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Linked topic contains stylesheet based answer, which I prefer, but also a programmatic one, you can put that script in init.m file as explained there. p.s. as always, let me know if you disagree with closing.

Comment: Thank you! Quite on the contrary, I am totally agree with your closing the question! :) And *of course* it's unsimple. It kind of worries me that simple features like this that would take 5 minutes to implement are never done, but instead we get a confusing bloat of just about everything imaginable. No, I have nothing against Mathematica supporting SeatGeek API and Fitbit integration out of the box, but maybe starting an open project on GitHub for packages like that and saving energy for fixing the basics would be a better approach on the WRI part. Oooh, rant over.